# Parse string with bash script to get last item

Tags: bash, string, sed

I have a file which contains multiple lines of this format:

```
Item A               62.7         97.9              9.0
Item A B C           54.2         98.4             10.0
Another Item A       51.0         98.8              7.0
Another Item A--B--C 57.0         98.8              1.0
```

**I would like to write a bash script that would take all the last values of each line**, (e.g. 9.0, 10.0, 7.0, and 1.0).

The problem that I am encountering is that I can't use `cut -d" " -f 4` since there are different number of spaces in the item names. Moreover, I cannot use 'more than 2 spaces' as a delimiter when using `sed` since sometimes there would be only one space between the item name and the second column (like in the last line in the example, between C and 5).

I thought maybe I could parse each line from the end, but I am not sure if that is doable. Any help will be appreciated, as I am not very familiar with bash scripting.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parsing the line from the end would be a good approach here. You could use `sed -e 's/^.* //'`

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind an extra comma at the end you can do this:

```
 awk '{$1=$1;print $NF}' ORS="," ./infile
```

Comment: @quark: I'm curious how the one you choose worked given your requirements that they should be separated by commas?  If that is not a requirement, then please remove that statement from your question because it is confusing for others. Thanks

Comment: I can add the commas in without much difficulty and I am just more familiar with sed than awk. But as I said, both answers are equally good answers for me (+1 for both but unfortunately I could only pick one as the answer). I will take the commas statement out from my question to make the question-answer better. :)

Comment: @quark: no problem, understandable

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking to get the last item in a delimited, you can always reverse the first item of a reversal of the delimited list.

```
echo ($LINE) | rev | cut -d" " -f1 | rev
```